# Excel VBA help documentation install

Tags: excel, chm, vba

How can VBA help full, offline accessible documentation install into Microsoft Excel 2013?

I have tried to download this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40326, but I cannot open help sections.

I have already tried to modify my installation, but cannot find any options related to this in setup.

Comment: Download from this link one by one files. No problems. If you select all or many there are problems.

Comment: But how to replace Excel's built in one? How to integrate this detailed version into Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a connected world security updates are a fact of life for a Long time. Microsoft have done a mighty job of securing Windows starting with XP SP2 released in Aug 2004. Since then a string of updates have reduced the humble CHM to the status of a humble local help system. It's a shame but we have had to move on.

Please note and make sure downloading your CHM's to a local drive!

Because files downloaded off the Internet - including ZIP files and CHM files contained in those zip files - are marked as as coming from the Internet and so can potentially be malicious, so do not get browsing rights on the local machine.

A explicitly 'unblock' of your downloaded CHM file may solve your problem. Please try in Windows Explorer and in a local drive (!) before going the next installation steps for Office 2013:

1. Open Windows Explorer and navigate to your download folder
2. Find your CHM file
3. Right click and select Properties
4. Click the Unblock button on the General tab

Here's what the dialog looks like:
[image]

I remember (not sure) the Unblock button may appear in NTFS filesystems only.

Answer (score 2):

Trick to open the file is double click the file. One pop-up as per image shown below will appear.
[image: pop up while opening file]

Please uncheck the tick mark ie remove it in the check-box `Always Ask before opening the file.`Then open it. It will be opened with its contents. HTH

Edit :
I am able to open these documents by trick adopted by me. Screen shots shown here.

[image: sample 1][image: sample2][image: sample3]

After opening Excel Developer Help File I am getting the index on the left side and selected page opened on the right side which can be fully navigated. Please let me know what you are looking for. Apart from this There is an opening page where references to web url's are presented.

[image: Excel Developer CHM file]

Comment: That is okay, but cannot open any section inside it.

Comment: @Kovacs Akos I have edited my answer showing samples of documents opened by me. I am ready to help in this regard further, if desired.

Comment: @Kovacs Akos Your point is its integration with Office 2013 installed on your PC. I tried out various methods but so far success has eluded me. Offline viewing is fine. Procedure mentioned in MS Documents does not work. I shall keep on trying.

Comment: @Kovacs Akos Sorry for delay in replying as I was asleep in the intervening period. I am able to fully open all links , pages. Some go to internet websites also. I have uploaded to drop box one of the documents <code>Access 2013 Developer Documentation</code>  You may please download from drop box and let me know if you still have problems with this document. <https://www.dropbox.com/s/nk11d5guoovodn2/Access%202013%20Developer%20Documentation.chm?dl=0.>

Comment: @Kovacs Akos  Does the uploaded file to drop box help you in any way

Comment: How does "precedence" page looks like in Excel 2013 Developer documentation? I cannot open these in these method that you described, because I get blank pages for all. I really need that page!

Comment: @Kovacs Akos I shall revert back to you in about half an hour.

Comment: Thanks, but please search for word "precedence" and take make please a screenshot from that page. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kovacs Akos can we move to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112043/discussion-between-kovacs-akos-and-skkakkar).

Comment: @Kovacs Akos I am back from some work. Are you available for chat.